# Как высветить все маркеры на карте Google во Flutter?

Tags: google-maps-api, flutter, dart

всем. У меня есть метод с помощью которого я высвечиваю все маркеры на 
гугл-картах, но проблема заключается в том что он не работает. Работает только один маркер, когда я его показываю только одного. Как я могу решить данную проблему?

> Вот код с одним маркером

```
allMarkers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('myMarker'),
          draggable: true,
          onTap: () {
            _showModal();
          },
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueMagenta),
          position: LatLng(widget.latitude, widget.longitude)));
```

> А вот уже метод с несколькими маркерами

```
void showAllMarkers() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      int count = prefs.getInt('count');
      var dbHelper = new DBHelper();
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        double latitude = await dbHelper.getLatitude(i);
        double longitude = await dbHelper.getLatitude(i);
        allMarkers.add(Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('myMarker'),
            draggable: true,
            onTap: () {
              _showModal();
            },
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueMagenta),
            position: LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
      }
  }
```

Comment: Делайте отладку кода, но мне кажется проблема в этом: `markerId: MarkerId('myMarker')`, у вас на все новые маркеры тот же id...

Answer (score 1):

Думаю решение такое:

```
void showAllMarkers() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int count = prefs.getInt('count');
  var dbHelper = new DBHelper();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    double latitude = await dbHelper.getLatitude(i);
    double longitude = await dbHelper.getLatitude(i);
    allMarkers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId("${latitude.toString()}-${longitude.toString()}"),
      draggable: true,
      onTap: () { _showModal(); },
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueMagenta),
      position: LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
  }
}
```